# Omit not working when interface has index signature

Tags: typescript

Running the latest version of Typescript (4.6.4) when my interface has an index signature  Omit doesn't work as expected. Not sure if this is expected behavior or I am misunderstanding something with index signatures.

```
interface Test1 {
  a: number;
  b: number;
}

// 'Property 'b' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Omit<Test1, "a">''
const test1: Omit<Test1, 'a'> = {};

interface Test2 {
  [key: string]: number;
  a: number;
  b: number;
}

// no issues
const test2: Omit<Test2, 'a'> = {};
```

I would expect that test2 would have the same error as test1.

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45367